# BIRT Report dynamically set width

Tags: eclipse, birt, opentext

I am having few rptDesign files in which width and height is set. When the report renders on browser this values (width and height ) shows with pt unit. I wanted to have this as % so that with the screen size it should enhance the generated report size. is this possible in BIRT ? if yes how?

Comment: You don't mention the output format of your report. Besides, if you edit the width and height properties in the property editor (instead of dragging with the mouse), you can enter % as a unit.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have editor. I have reportdesign file and in that width and height is given. When the report is rendered in my browser it shows the unit is pt. I want that to be %. It will help me to handle responsiveness.

Comment: Report format is html / SVG / PNG

Answer (score 0):

@JAVA_CAT

If you want to set the height and width of a report then select Master Page from the tab menu, then click the properties tab directly beneath > Here you can see & set the height and width which can be changed to percentages.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2M2T.jpg)

Comment: unfortunately I don't have editor. I have reportdesign file and in that width and height is given. When the report is rendered in my browser it shows the unit is pt. I want that to be %. It will help me to handle responsiveness.

Comment: Already width is there but % not working. Is it because of the version ?

Comment: @JAVA_CAT I see, if you only have the the reportdesign file, are you able to edit this in Notepad or Notepad++ ?

Comment: yes I can and I am able to see the width and  height. The unit is either in pt or inch. I changed that to % then it is not compiling and not rendering.

Comment: I saw this which might help you: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884402/how-to-size-svg-using-percentage